# Initial value is stored in the variable after calling Angular Component method in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I have a component as follows:

```
// customer-reservation.component.ts
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-reservation',
  template: ``
})
export class CustomerReservationComponent {
  customerCount = 10;

  registerCustomer() {
    return this.customerCount++;
  }

  unregisterCustomer() {
    return this.customerCount--;
  }
}
```

Following is specs file for above component:

```
// customer-reservation.component.spec.ts
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import { CustomerReservationComponent } from "./customerReservation.component";

describe('Room Reservation', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CustomerReservationComponent>;
  let component: CustomerReservationComponent;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        CustomerReservationComponent
      ]
    })

    // Set-up
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CustomerReservationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

  })

  afterEach(() => {
    // Tear-down
    fixture = null;
    component = null;
  })

  it('Increase customer count in case of registration', () => {
    let customerCount: number;
    customerCount = component.registerCustomer();    // This is still 10
    expect(customerCount).toEqual(11);               // test fails

  })

  it('Decrease customer count in case of registration', () => {
    let customerCount: number;
    customerCount = component.unregisterCustomer(); // This is still 10
    expect(customerCount).toEqual(9);               // test fails
  })
})
```

I didn't understand why `customerCount` variable has value 10 in both cases. It should have 11 and 9 value respectively stored for the specs. But, when I replace `customerCount` with `component.customerCount`, tests are run successfully. Can someone please help me why earlier approach is not updating local `customerCount` variable with incremented and decremented value for respective tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return this.customerCount++;` will always return the value of `this.customerCount` before incrementing it.

To make it work with the local variable, you can use the prefix increment/decrement operator:

```
  registerCustomer() {
    return ++this.customerCount;
  }

  unregisterCustomer() {
    return --this.customerCount;
  }
```

Comment: Yep. Missed that. Thanks!